# linux group by date column and show count

Tags: linux, bash, shell

i have a CSV file that looks like this:

```
aaa bbb ccc, 2015-01-01
fff ggg ddd, 2015-01-01
ggg hhh sss, 2015-01-02
ddd fff aaa, 2015-01-03
sss kkk www, 2015-01-03
```

i want to group by the second field (date). 
`cat myfile.csv | sort -t, k2 |uniq -c` 
printed 1 next to every line which is wrong.

i want this:

```
2015-01-01 2
2015-01-02 1
2015-01-03 2
```

Comment: for `uniq -c` to work the way you wanted you need to drop the irrelevant part of the line first: `cat myfile.csv | cut -d, -f2 | sort | uniq -c`

Comment: Very good.  `uniq -c` will, however, never directly produce the output in the desired order: date then count.  One would need something like: `cut -d, -f2 myfile.csv | sort | uniq -c | awk '{print $2,$1}'` (where I have also removed the [UUOC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cat_%28Unix%29#Useless_use_of_cat).)

Answer (score 0):

This assumes, as in your example, that the dates are in order:

```
$ awk -F, 'NR>1 && d!=$2 {print d,c;c=0} {c++; d=$2;} END{print d,c;}' myfile.csv 
 2015-01-01 2
 2015-01-02 1
 2015-01-03 2
```